# jupyter-kernelspec' not found, when executing Pkg.build("IJulia")

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, julia, ijulia-notebook

Please, trying to rebuild IJulia given I am not able to launch it via Anaconda navigator (I receive the red `kernel error`). With the command `Pkg.build("IJulia")`, below is the output:

`INFO: Building Conda`

`INFO: Building MbedTLS`

`===============================[ ERROR: MbedTLS]============================`

`LoadError: unlink: operation not permitted (EPERM)`
  `while loading C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\MbedTLS\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 40`

`==============================================================================`
  `INFO: Building ZMQ`

`INFO: Building IJulia`

`INFO: Installing Jupyter via the Conda package.`

`INFO: Found Jupyter version 4.3.0:`

`C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\Conda\deps\usr\Scripts\jupyter`
  `INFO: Installing Julia kernelspec julia-0.6`

`Error executing Jupyter command 'kernelspec': [Errno 'jupyter-kernelspec' not found] 2`

`[InstallKernelSpec] Removing existing kernelspec in` 
  `C:\Users\s1364322\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\julia-0.6`

`[InstallKernelSpec] Installed kernelspec julia-0.6 in` 
  `C:\Users\s1364322\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\julia-0.6`

`================================[ BUILD ERRORS]=============================`

`WARNING: MbedTLS had build errors.`

`- packages with build errors remain installed in C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6`
   `- build the package(s) and all dependencies with Pkg.build("MbedTLS")`

`- build a single package by running its deps/build.jl script`

`===============================================================================`

When I try `Pkg.build("MbedTLS")`, the output is:

`LoadError: unlink: operation not permitted (EPERM)
while loading C:\Users\s1364322\.julia\v0.6\MbedTLS\deps\build.jl, in expression starting on line 40`

Please, how can I get the way around?

This is my version info:

Julia Version 0.6.0
Commit 903644385b* (2017-06-19 13:05 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Windows (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell)
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.9.1 (ORCJIT, skylake)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems to be a permission issue. Where are you running the commands (juno or cmd or powershell)? Try opening that program, whichever it is, as Administrator, and then run Pkg.build again (after a Pkg.update preferably). Btw, as a side remark, there is 0.6.3 version of Julia out now, with a lot of bugfixes over the 0.6.0, so you might want to upgrade to that (won't affect your package installations).

Comment: Thans for the upgrading suggestion. I am able to successfully launch IJulia (Jupiter notebook) via the Julia REPL. (But not directly Jupyter notebook via Anaconda). I proceeded as you (@sundar) suggested, but the same error messages come out